# Concatenating child array to parent

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Right now I have an array of object with children that also have an array of objects.

```
 [
  {
    "code": "mock-code",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [
      {
        "code": "mock-child-code",
        "name": "mock-child-name",
      },
      {
        "code": "mock-child-code",
        "name": "mock-child-name",
      },
    ],
  },
 {
    "code": "mock-code",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [],
  },
 {
    "code": "mock-code",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [
      {
       "code": "mock-code",
       "name": "mock-name",
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I want to extract the children array and concat them to the parent array like below.

```
 [
  {
    "code": "m1",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [
      {
        "code": "mc-1",
        "name": "mn-1",
      },
      {
        "code": "mc-2",
        "name": "mn-2",
      },
    ],
  },
 {
    "code": "m2",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [],
  },
 {
    "code": "mm3",
    "name": "mock-name",
    "children": [
      {
       "code": "mc-3",
       "name": "mn-3",
      }
    ],
  }
  {
    "code": "mc-1",
    "name": "mn-1",
  },
  {
    "code": "mc-2",
    "name": "mn-2",
  },
   {
    "code": "mc-3",
    "name": "mn-3",
  }
]
```

What are someways to do this. I'm currently looping though the child array creating a new array checking if it's not empty. It all seems a bit messy. Is there a clean way to do this?

```
   let fullList = New Array()
   parentData.forEach(element => {
      if (!!element.children.length) {
       fullList.push(element.children);
      }
    });

   return parentData.concat(fullList);
```

This isn't giving me the desired results since it's adding another array to the parent object but this is where I am at.

Comment: your example doesnt really make much sense.  It would probably be easier to show what you have coded already to see what logic you are trying to apply.  At the minute I can't see how you get from the first example to the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newArray = originalArray.flatMap(element => [element, ...element.children])
```

This should do it, and as a bonus will preserve the order (parent1, parent1's children, parent2, parent2's children etc.)

Of course, this works if you have only one level of nesting. If you have greater depth level, that would be a bit more complex, probably using Array.prototype.reduce().

Comment: That actually works perfect. Short and concise thanks a ton!

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a reducer and .concat function instead?

Comment: @Murtz It would make sense if you have more levels of nesting in your arrays as the flatMap has a depth of 1 when flattening arrays. Alternatively you could use the flat() function which takes a depth parameter so it can flatten recursively. With reduce you could create a more generic solution and with additional logic if necessary, but if you need just flattening, flatMap and flat are a bit more optimized and would probably give you better performance,

Comment: I'm just wondering since flatMap isn't fully supported with all the browsers wondering about a backup solution if possible

Comment: Of course, the reducer with concat would definitely work, but flatMap should be supported by most modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=flatMap. Also don't know your project setup, but you can consider using Babel if you're not certain about support for more modern features.